# SQL COALESCE to "skip" custom value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `COALESCE` function as follows:

```sql
COALESCE(date1, date2, date3)
```

However, because of an upstream process I do not control, "date2" NULLs were transformed into '1900-01-01'

My goal is to: SELECT date1, if date1 null select date2, but only if date2 is not '1900-01-01' - otherwise select date3.

What is the best way to write this? I want to avoid a clunky CASE WHEN statement if possible

Comment: Honestly, the "best" way would be to fix your data; don't use arbitrary dates to represent `NULL`, use `NULL` to represent `NULL`. That being said, have you looked at `NULLIF`?

Comment: Why to avoid CASE WHEN? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Larnu unfortunately I don't have control over the incoming data stream. But NULLIF is a great solution here, thanks. If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as solution

Comment: "Clunky" is how you do it.  `COALESCE(date1, Case When date2<>'1900-01-01' Then date2 End, date3)`.  Verbose, yes, clunky, no.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I did not realize I could do CASE WHEN inside the COALESCE, that is less clunky than only using CASE WHEN by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, really the data needs fixing. I realise you state that this is upstream, but if this is a problem then feedback upstream that it's a problem and get it fixed. *Don't* use arbitrary values for values that should be `NULL`; use `NULL`.

For the data as you have it at the moment, you can use `NULLIF` to return `NULL` is the value is equal to another. If this is just for `date2` then you would do the following:

```sql
COALESCE(date1, NULLIF(date2,'19000101'), date3)
```